# "netMsmqBinding" lost message

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, msmq, netmsmqbinding, msmq-wcf

I have a WF4 that its hosted in a Windows Service and works with netMsmqBinding. 
All works well when the service its started. The service read the private queue and process the message okey.

The problem is when the windows services is stop, i execute the client and i put the message in the queue. But when i then start the windows services the message disapear of the queue but never start to process. If i send other message to the queue with the service started it process okey, but i lose al the message that enter to the queue when the service was stoped.

Comment: Can you provide the binding configuration/properties? There are many options that could be affecting this. Look at TTL, sendTimeout, durable flag. etc